# Will NSNotificationCreation impact on application performance?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

In my code i have a lot of `NSNotification` around 200+ .

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver....];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName...];
```

Will this impact on my application performance if I register and fire notification a lot?

Comment: That purely depends on how are you handling it.

Comment: you should remove particular notification after its use. else that called twise or more... better to use Custom Delegate protocol for doing same work. that much better instead of NSNotification center.

Comment: To expand upon @NitinGohel's point, use `NSNotificationCentre` for to-many communication, and delegates or callbacks for to-one. What is the relationship here? Also, if it's possible that duplicate notifications are sent out you could look into the coalescing features of [`NSNotificationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotificationQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: You should have a look at [tolo](https://github.com/genzeb/tolo)

Comment: what if i want to use notification throughout the app? don't want to remove?

Comment: what if i will not remove and add notification again and again?

Comment: if you not remove notification and add again and again its called multiple time and its effect on your app  performance

Comment: Have a look at Tolo, then ask yourself, "Why should I adopt an abstraction of a standard abstraction?" The runtime and OS provide NSNotifications, which are well understood by ObjectiveC programmers and are quite sturdy.

Answer (score 2):

This is depend on how to handle `NSNotificationCenter` in your code.if you handle your `NSNotification` purely then its effect bcoz its called `twice or more times..`

best approach for  `NSNotification` is you add in your `viewWillAppear` and remove it on `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: Beware of the [viewMightAppear:](http://blog.supertop.co/post/80781694515/viewmightappear) syndrome that arose with iOS 7.

Comment: when i want to use it throughout the app?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `NSNotificationCenter` you should have a look at [tolo](https://github.com/genzeb/tolo)

The biggest advantage is that you don't have to care about adding/removing observers - tolo does this for you automagically.

ps. failing to remove any observer might lead to retain cycles and memory leaks